# How do you test Facebook apps that have been released when the auth only calls back to one URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook only allows its authorization system to redirect to one URL... for me it is index.php. Typically, when I release new things I release them to test.php or something similar before replacing index, so that I can make sure it works.

Is this possible with Facebook? Or do i just have to release every update straight to index.php and pray it works or debug as quickly as possible if it doesn't?

---

Here is the Facebook error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, redirect_uri can be different on the same domain, so I don't think you will have some problems using another redirect_uri

Comment: they say it can but it doesn't work - Facebook registers an error when you try to redirect to yoursite.com/other.php.... it could be a bug

Comment: It started working again - I'm not sure what the issue was but you are right with redirect_uri... I guess this issue for me is more generally about debugging facebook apps before releasing them (eg, you can't do it on localhost) but perhaps i'll try again with a clearer question. thanks!